# log4net Logging Debug.WriteLine and Console.WriteLine

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I recently came accross log4net thanks to a user here. Anyways, I am wanting to log every Console.Write() and Debug.Write() automatically to the single log file I have configured. Also, I use many class libraries that also have Console/Debug statements that know nothing about log4net. Can these also be logged to the log file automatically based on the configuration? Is any of this possible?

What I want logged in the rolling log file:

```
Console.WriteLine("console statement");
Debug.WriteLine("debug statement");
```

Instantiate Logger:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
private static void InitializeLogger()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Entire app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="SubToolsPortServerTest.log"/>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redirect `Debug.WriteLine` (in debug builds) and `Trace.WriteLine` to log4net by writing a custom `TraceListener` that logs to log4net.  The salient bits of a simplistic implementation will look something like:

```
public class Log4NetTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    ILog _logger = ...;

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        _logger.Info(message);
    }
}
```

You would then configure this in your application configuration file something like:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  ...
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" type="MyNamespace.Log4NetTraceListener,MyAssembly" />
    </listeners>
   ...
</system.diagnostics>
```

A more complete implementation might support configuration of the logger name, the logging level to use, and perhaps some internal buffering of messages.

For `Console.WriteLine` you could redirect to your own custom `TextWriter` by calling `Console.SetOut`, and your custom `TextWriter` could log to log4net.

Comment: Joe, I am accepting your answer as it answers my question regarding outputting Debug and Console.WriteLines to log4net. However, I have found it easier to add log4net to each project and change the debug statements. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone experience deadlocks doing this?